# Prevent select box from changing to default using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, frontend

[image]

I have a On Click `Add More positions` which appends some Html which consist of Select tag.
When ever I trigger this event It will generate the html and append to it's child. This have multiple select tag which have dynamic values. But the issue is that when I click on event all the previous select box changing to default value or index. My code below.

```
document.getElementById("positionsadd").addEventListener("click", function() {

        var min=498; 
        var max=875;  
        random =Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min; 
        let f = 1;
        htmlClone = 
        `<tr class="mainrow${random}" id="mainrow${random}">
            <td>
                <table class="position">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="position-numbers position-numbers-clone${random}" >


                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td class="select-technique">
                <select class="technique-class${random}" id="technique-class${random}" onchange="myOnChange(this)">

                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table class="choose_colors">
                    <tbody class="choose_colors_body">
                        <tr>
                            <td><span>1</span></td>
                            <td><span>2</span></td>
                            <td><span>3</span></td>
                            <td><span>4</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><span>5</span></td>
                            <td><span>6</span></td>
                            <td><span>7</span></td>
                            <td><span>8</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table class="choose_size">
                    <tr>
                        <td>H</td>
                        <td><input type="" name="vh" value="50" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>w</td>
                        <td><input type="" name="vw" value="46" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <label>48.00 INR</label>
            </td>
            <td colspan="2" class="clear${random}">
                <label>X</label>
            </td>
        </tr>`;

        cloneDoc.innerHTML += htmlClone;

});
```

Comment: provide the html and css

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem for `select` and `input` fields as the other values have not appeared for missing of Html and CSS. Hope it works.

```html
<button type='button' id="positionsadd">click</button>

<table id='cloneDoc'></table>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
  $("table").change(function(event) {
    console.log(event.target);

    if (event.target.nodeName == 'INPUT')
      $(event.target).attr('value', event.target.value);
    if (event.target.nodeName == 'SELECT')
      $(event.target).find('option:selected')[0].setAttribute('selected', true);

  });


  document.getElementById("positionsadd").addEventListener("click", function() {

    var min = 498;
    var max = 875;
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    let f = 1;
    htmlClone =
      `<tr class="mainrow${random}" id="mainrow${random}">
    <td>
        <table class="position">
            <tbody>
                <tr class="position-numbers position-numbers-clone${random}" >


                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td class="select-technique">
        <select class="technique-class${random}" id="technique-class${random}" onclick="myOnChange(this)">
                <option value="one">One</option>
                 <option value="two">Two</option>
        </select>
        
    </td>
    <td>
        <table class="choose_colors">
            <tbody class="choose_colors_body">
                <tr>
                    <td><span>1</span></td>
                    <td><span>2</span></td>
                    <td><span>3</span></td>
                    <td><span>4</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>5</span></td>
                    <td><span>6</span></td>
                    <td><span>7</span></td>
                    <td><span>8</span></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td>
        <table class="choose_size">
            <tr>
                <td>H</td>
                <td><input type="" name="vh" value="50" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>w</td>
                <td><input type="" name="vw" value="46" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
        <label>48.00 INR</label>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2" class="clear${random}">
        <label>X</label>
    </td>
</tr>`;

    document.getElementById('cloneDoc').innerHTML += htmlClone;

  });

  function myOnChange(params) {
    console.log(params);

  }
</script>
```